# Can JSL tool (http://jslwin.sourceforge.net/index.html) be used on Linux?

Tags: java, linux

Hi I have the jsl tool (http://jslwin.sourceforge.net/index.html) already in the code to run the java process on windows as services.
But now the requirement is to run the java process as a service on Linux machine.
I have tried to run the code on Linux and getting no error/exception at run time. But as of now I am not sure this is working properly or not.

So my question is , can this tool be used on Linux machine as well?

Comment: there are all windows *.exe file, which can't run directly on linux. But [wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) may can run them.

Comment: Thanks . Can you suggest the alternative to this JSL for Linux boxes?